# How to make dashed wave line in css

Tags: css

i wanted to make the background line a dashed wavy line tried using div with border-style: dashed and border-radius, but couldn't achieve it. how to make this marked line (refer to attached image) as background in CSS.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if you can achieve this with plain CSS. I would use SVG as background image.

Comment: @Jax-p
okay thanks for your quick response .

Comment: You might be able to achieve using an element with a radius and some elements to "cover" it so it will "cut" and hide the other part of the circle, but that route is quite hacky.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that I can think about (without having javascript/svg and just pure html and css) is to combine `border-style: dashed`, `border-radius` and a couple of "cover" elements to "cut" and hide the radial elements.

check this one.
https://jsfiddle.net/fco0v79p/1/ (just need to proper position it to make it flawless)

Although I'm warning you that this is quite hacky, tedious, and inflexible.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use Hr tag for horizontal line and apply styling on the top of that like this.

```
hr {
  border:none;
  border-top:1px dotted #f00;//or use can use dahshed
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#fff;
  height:1px;
  width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not done by CSS. it is probably SVG or PNG.

here is the link to PNG you can use => [wave.png](https://www.nicepng.com/ourpic/u2q8y3e6u2r5e6y3_drawing-curved-dotted-lines-curved-dotted-line-png/)

If you want to do it with CSS maybe you can use the code below. (but with straight lines for less problem)

```css
/* just setting up background*/
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.parent-dashed{
background-color:#181A2F;
height:100vh;
width:100%;
}

/* main css */
.dashed{
width:200px;
border:none;
border-bottom:10px dashed #e7e7e7;
position:absolute;
}

/* position lines where you want */
.line1{
top:35%;
transform:rotate(3deg);
}
.line2{
top:30%;
right:0;
transform:rotate(-3deg);
}
.line3{
top:80%;
right:0;
transform:rotate(5deg);
width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent-dashed'>
  <div class='dashed line1'></div>
  <div class='dashed line2'></div>
  <div class='dashed line3'></div>
</div>
```